# Does Google Drive integrate with Android through code?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have spent some hours searching for Android phone integrations with Google Drive through code. But I am not able to figure it out. I want to make a app in which when I press a button, my specific file is uploaded and stored in Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, GoogleDrive is not integrated with Android.  However, this is something they are working on and say it will be here "soon".  The services theyre working on is called [Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/google-play-services/).

You can also currently use the [java client library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) to accomplish what you need for now.

Just a warning, there aren't many great examples out there so its somewhat difficult to figure out.